# Is it possible to generate a class with interface using Visual Studio Connected Services (OpenApi)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-connected-services

I have a unit tests in my app. Noticed, that generated class by Visual Studio Connected Services for OpenApi does not implement an interface for the API class. That means it will be not possible to test. Is there any simple way make it possible to generate an interface for that?